# Call Open Weather API with React Native

Tags: react-native, weather-api

I am experimenting with Open Weather. I trying to replace the innerHTML of a Text element with the temperature number. If I alert the const temperature I get undefined....

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Button, Alert, Text, View, ImageBackground, TextInput} from 'react-native';
const openweather_api = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=V&appid=somenumberss&units=metric";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {};

  componentDidMount(){
    async function getWeather() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(openweather_api);  
        const json = await response.json();
        console.log(json) // works, it returns the weather data..
        alert(json.main.temp) // works, it returns 2 degrees. 
        this.setState({
          temperature: json.main.temp,
          humidity: json.main.humidity,
        });
        } catch (e) {
        alert('something went wrong')
        }
      }
    getWeather();
  }

  render() {
alert(json.main.temp) // gets undefined.. 
console.log(this.state) // returns {} __proto__.....

  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
     <Text>Today's temperature is {this.state.temperature} Celcius</Text>
    <Text>{this.state.humidity > 100 && this.state.temperature > 20 ? 'nice weather' : 'bad weather'}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

}
```

Comment: Where are you calling your getWeather function? And please use state once you get the result, and in the render you can then display this state.

Comment: Thank you for the input. The getWeather() is called right away. So you mean that I should do a setState within the if and else statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developing it into an answer. 
A normal workflow would be something like this:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    temperature: 0,
    humidity: 0,
  };

componentDidMount() {
  this.getWeather();
}

function getWeather() {
      fetch(openweather_api).then(res => res.json)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('data', data)
        this.setState({
          temperature: data.main.temp,
          humidity: data.main.humidity,
        });
    }

render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.weather}>
          <Text>Today's temperature is {this.state.temperature} Celcius</Text>
          <Text>{this.state.humidity > 100 && this.state.temperature > 20 ? 'It's nice outside, go for a run!' : 'It's too cold to run outside'}</Text>
        </View>
}
```

And you call your function in `componentDidMount`.

Of course it's not perfect, but you get the idea. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Drax if this is working for you, could you please mark the answer as accepted, so that others know that there is no need for other answers :) Glad to have helped!

Comment: Thanks again. The logic is better now, but I still can't seem to the numbers from temperature and humidity. Do you have any suggestions? I've updated the code

Comment: Can you log what json is returning? Straight after `const json = ...`, do a console.log of json and see what object it's returning.

Comment: It returns: {coord: {…}, weather: Array(1), base: "stations", main: {…}, visibility: 10000, …}   I also updated the code. Logging json.main.temp works fine as well. Perhaps it's a scope issue?

Comment: Shouldn't be. And if you log just `this.state` inside the render? To see if there are any changes.

Comment: console.log(this.state) inside render, i get:  {}
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()

Comment: Just changed to code to move away from async/await, can you try it this way? It should be fine.

Comment: I tried to remove async and await, but still no luck

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2yaahz. Please try this, I'm getting unauthorized, but it should be ok otherwise. And please make sure that data console.log returns what you want.

Comment: Thanks for sticking on this this. It helped a great deal :)